# How to init map with values

Tags: go

I have a multi-line map creation and setting of values in Go.

```golang
type Animal struct {
  food, locomotion, sound string
}

type AnimalInterface interface {
  Eat()
  Move()
  Speak()
}
```

```golang
animals := make(map[string]Animal)
animals["cow"] = Animal{"grass", "walk", "moo"}
animals["bird"] = Animal{"worms", "fly", "peep"}
animals["snake"] = Animal{"mice", "slither", "hsss"}
```

I'd prefer to do the create and init in a single step. This doesn't work ... how should I fix it?

```golang
animals := map[string]Animal{
  "cow": Animal{"grass", "walk", "moo"}
  "bird": Animal{"worms", "fly", "peep"}
  "snake": Animal{"mice", "slither", "hsss"}
}
```

*EDIT* 
Added commas

```golang
  animals := map[string]Animal{
    "cow": Animal{"grass", "walk", "moo"},
    "bird": Animal{"worms", "fly", "peep"},
    "snake": Animal{"mice", "slither", "hsss"}
  }
```

```
❯ go run animals.go
# command-line-arguments
./animals.go:109:47: syntax error: unexpected newline, expecting comma or }
```

Comment: What is class Animal like? You're also missing commas after each kvp in the map.

Comment: Thanks @Sdyess I added the class definition. I tried adding commas but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo. You missed commas after map elements.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Animal struct {
    food, locomotion, sound string
}

type AnimalInterface interface {
    Eat()
    Move()
    Speak()
}

func main() {
    animals := map[string]Animal{
        "cow": Animal{"grass", "walk", "moo"},
        "bird": Animal{"worms", "fly", "peep"},
        "snake": Animal{"mice", "slither", "hsss"},
    }

    fmt.Println(animals)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hTy8kYkAo08)

Comment: So when defaulting a map we need a comma after every value, even the last! Thanks!